# R Shiny Line Plot with Multiple Lines

Tags: r, shiny

I am having the hardest time getting a multi-line plot in R. I am new to R and none of the existing suggestions are working for me.

I would like to graph a different line for each pheno with time+1 on x and adj_sc on y.

Small example of data I am pulling from an excel spreadsheet (marginal_plot_data):

| time | adj_sc | pheno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 0.94 | 1 |
| -1 | 1.39 | 2 |
| -1 | 1.35 | 3 |
| 1 | 0.84 | 1 |
| 1 | 1.58 | 2 |
| 1 | 1.46 | 3 |

and here is dput(aa)

```
c(`intercept class1` = 5.52, `intercept class2` = 4.66, 
`intercept class3` = 3.69, `intercept class4` = 2.79, 
`time class1` = 0.03, `time class2` = 0.84, 
`time class3` = 0.35, `time class4` = 0.66,
`time2 class1` = -0.57, `time2 class2` = -0.03, 
`time2 class3` = -0.89, `time2 class4` = 0.08,
`RENAME` = 0.045, 
nsex = 0.83, brace = 0.67, orace = 0.04, 
stderr = 0.68)
```

Here is some code to go off of:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

marginal_plot_data<-read_xlsx( path="PATH_TO/PLOT_DATA.xlsx" ) 
load(file="PATH_TO/RENAME_FILE.Rda" )
aa <- rename( aa, c( "RENAME" = "NEW_NAME" ) )

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("constPlot")
}

server <- function( input, output, session ) {
  output$constPlot <- renderPlot({
    sub_data1 <- as.data.frame( marginal_plot_data )
    sub_data5 <- sub_data1 %>% group_by(pheno)
    sub_data10 <- as.data.frame(sub_data5)
    plo <- ggplot(data=sub_data10, aes(x=time, y=adj_sc, group=pheno)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point()
    fig <- ggplot(plo)
    fig
  })
}
```

Here is the current error I am getting, however it is ever-changing lol:

> Error in UseMethod("rename") :
> no applicable method for 'rename' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

When adding plyr. infront of the rename function I get the same error.

When removing plyr and trying to use dplyr's rename I get the same error.

Using rename with plyr before adding dplyr the rename worked without issue, but I was unable to get the graph code to work.

Comment: is `aa` some data frame or other object loaded in with `load()`? To me it looks like you could try changing the rename to `rename(aa,NEW_NAME=RENAME)`. But there are other options for renaming in base R such as `colnames(aa) <- c("Col1_name","Col2_name",...)`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Comment: could you provide `dput(aa)`?

Comment: @Baroque aa is not a dataframe, it is a named vector. It used to work before I added dplyr.

Comment: @Waldi I added the dput (:

Comment: Is the question specific to using Shiny? If not, that just complicates matters by a lot both for us and for you to try to debug. Keep in mind the *minimal* part of [mcve] and see if there are places to narrow down the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `rename` line with

```
names(aa)[names(aa)=="RENAME"] <- "NEW_NAME"
```

And it should work. Something is happening with the call to the rename function, but this does the same job with base R.